# Excel VBA - Batch find and replace of formula

Tags: vba, excel, batch-processing

Trying to determine correct way to complete a batch find and replace of formulas, i.e.

`Worksheet 1` has columns `A` and `B`.  `A` is the find column and `B` is the replace column.

`Worksheet 2` has lots of rows and columns with lots of formulas.  This is the worksheet I want the find and replace to actually occur on.

I want Excel to look in the formulas on `Worksheet 2`, not the values.

The values in `Worksheet 1` one are not the whole contents of formulas in `Worksheet 2`, just parts (I think I need to use `xlPart`) somewhere.

Anyone know how to write a script that will look through `Worksheet 2` for formulas listed as values in `Worksheet 1`, column `A`, and then replace with the value on the same row of `Worksheet 1` in column `B`?

Comment: Have you tried some partial solution? It looks like you're giving this to us, like a school exercise to resolve for you...

Comment: It sounds like you want to enumerate the formulas in Worksheet2 that use functions listed in column A of Worksheet1. If `SUM` is listed in Worksheet1's column A, what happens if there are two or more `=SUM(...)` formulas in Worksheet2?

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know **how** to write a script

Well the easiest way is through the VBA editor.
If you intend to target the whole of Sheet 2, you're going to need to make use of the UsedRange property.

After that, it's not too difficult to write a formula that loops through a range (that you obtained using the UsedRange property).

In your loop, you're going to need to get its' formula, then use the Replace function to replace instances of your search string with your replacement string. If you want, you can loop here in worksheet 1 to do the replacement step for multiple pairs.

Once you've done that you should probably handle errors (unless you're absolutely certain that your replacements will ALWAYS result in a good formula), because Excel will argue with you if you try to put in a bad formula.

Without too much effort, this can probably all be done in about 30 lines of code (or less if you're tricky enough).